# Using reduce on map of array to calculate difference between values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects as follows which I want to map over:

```
  Array (3) 
    0 {_id: "5fea07cd143fd50008ae1ab2", newBalance: 1500, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:29:00.391Z"} 
    1 {_id:"5fea0837b2a0530009f3886f", newBalance: 1115, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:30:45.217Z"}
    2 {_id: "5fec30faef904e0dd1e39c60", newBalance: 1415, balanceDate: "2020-12-30T07:49:13.214Z"}
```

The function I'm using to map over this is as follows:

```
        { debtBalance.map ((debt, index) => {
              return (
                  <div className="transaction-history">
                    <div className="transaction-history-entry" key={index}>
                      <p><Moment date={debt.balanceDate} format="Do MMM" /></p>
                      <p>-£{debt.newBalance}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              )
            })
        }
```

I want to alter my map function though to implement a reduce of the 'newBalance' entries in each of these objects - to then compare the current value with the previous value, and figure out the difference between the two.

I thought it would be something like as follows...

```
debt.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
   return previousValue.newBalance - currentValue.newBalance
})
```

But with that I'm getting 'debt.reduce is undefined'.

Once I've set up the reduce function, I just want to render the difference in my app, but that'll be straightforward.

Any pointers would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Souldnt it be `debtBalance.reduce(..)`?

Comment: `reduce` is defined for array type. it seems like `debt` is not array object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I’d have thought that the mapping would then go through each of the array elements. Do you know how I’d alter my code to resolve this?

Comment: what's your expected output from the example input?

Comment: I guess the first one would be 0, then 385, -300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `Array.map` or `Array.reduce`.

```js
const debtBalance = [
  {
    _id: '5fea07cd143fd50008ae1ab2',
    newBalance: 1500,
    balanceDate: '2020-12-28T16:29:00.391Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '5fea0837b2a0530009f3886f',
    newBalance: 1115,
    balanceDate: '2020-12-28T16:30:45.217Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '5fec30faef904e0dd1e39c60',
    newBalance: 1415,
    balanceDate: '2020-12-30T07:49:13.214Z'
  }
];

// Using Array.map
const diffs1 = debtBalance.map((item, index) =>
  index === 0 ? 0 : debtBalance[index - 1].newBalance - item.newBalance
);

console.log(diffs1);

// Using Array.reduce
const diffs2 = debtBalance
  .map(item => item.newBalance)
  .reduce(
    (val, cur, index, original) => [
      ...val,
      index === 0 ? 0 : original[index - 1] - original[index]
    ],
    []
  );

console.log(diffs2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use reduce for this, it's not meant for this type of transformation. There is nothing to accumulate, all you want to do is look back one array element and calculate something. This is the same procedure for every array element, so .map is the right choice.

```
const balances = [
    {_id: "5fea07cd143fd50008ae1ab2", newBalance: 1500, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:29:00.391Z"},
    {_id:"5fea0837b2a0530009f3886f", newBalance: 1115, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:30:45.217Z"},
    {_id: "5fec30faef904e0dd1e39c60", newBalance: 1415, balanceDate: "2020-12-30T07:49:13.214Z"}
];
balances.map(
    (balance, index) => ({
        ...balance,
        difference: index >= 1 ? (balances[index - 1].newBalance - balance.newBalance) : 0
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've never heard of difference before. How would I implement this into my original map? I can't change that because it's how I'm rendering what I need to display each 'difference' as.

Comment: @JonNicholson difference was just a name for the property in the object that is returned in every map iteration. In your original code you'd only need to render `{index >= 1 ? (debt[index - 1].newBalance - debt.newBalance) : 0}` in your JSX.

Comment: @JonNicholson Someone else posted the same solution with .map later on, now it is the accepted answer. I don't mind, but would happily take an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly reduce during renderization, but it might be simpler to prepare your data up front,

here's an example of how to use reduce for mapping:

```js
var data = [
  {_id: "5fea07cd143fd50008ae1ab2", newBalance: 1500, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:29:00.391Z"},
  {_id:"5fea0837b2a0530009f3886f", newBalance: 1115, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:30:45.217Z"},
  {_id: "5fec30faef904e0dd1e39c60", newBalance: 1415, balanceDate: "2020-12-30T07:49:13.214Z"}
]

var res = data.reduce((ac, item) => {
  var previous = ac.length && ac[ac.length - 1]
  var diff = previous && previous.newBalance - item.newBalance
  var augmented = item
  augmented.diff = diff
  return [  // we'll output an array, because that's what you'll need later
    ...ac, // you push in previous results
    augmented
  ]
}, [])

console.log('res', res)
```